# Getting all selected checkboxes in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtml

So I have these checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />
```

And so on. There are about 6 of them and are hand-coded (i.e not fetched from a db) so they are likely to remain the same for a while.

My question is how I can get them all in an array (in javascript), so I can use them while making an AJAX `$.post` request using Jquery.

Any thoughts?

Edit: I would only want the selected checkboxes to be added to the array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery multiple checkboxes array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166763/jquery-multiple-checkboxes-array)

Comment: While the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166763/jquery-multiple-checkboxes-array) is newer and this one is more popular, the other one has a better, more succinct collection of answers (including the strategies here, plus some).

Answer (score 413, accepted):

Formatted :

```
$("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function(){
    yourArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: and what to do if uncheck check box, to remove value from array

Comment: @JubinPatel you just need to reset the array before this code. `yourArray = []`

Comment: You can also define your array immediately using `map` instead of `each`: `var yourArray = $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get()`

Comment: `function get_selected_checkboxes_array(){
                                    var ch_list=Array();
                                    $("input:checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){ch_list.push($(this).val());});
                                    return ch_list;
                                    }`

Comment: Okay Hear me out. what if the checkbox has multiple data Attribute and each attribute need to be added in the array

Like:
Array checkbox[
{name:"name", price:"100", shipping:"10", discount:"10"},
{name:"name", price:"100", shipping:"10", discount:"10"},
{name:"name", price:"100", shipping:"10", discount:"10"},
{name:"name", price:"100", shipping:"10", discount:"10"},
]

Answer (score 141):

**Pure JS**

For those who don't want to use jQuery

```
var array = []
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  array.push(checkboxes[i].value)
}
```

Comment: Always love a vanilla JS answer.

Comment: yes some time we really don't want to use jQuery

Comment: Also your solution with map function for vanilla JS. ```Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='type']:checked")).map((elem) => elem.value)```

Answer (score 57):

```
var chk_arr =  document.getElementsByName("chkRights[]");
var chklength = chk_arr.length;             

for(k=0;k< chklength;k++)
{
    chk_arr[k].checked = false;
}
```

Comment: As I understand the code above, it iterates through all the checkboxes and uncheck them. How this answer is connected with the question?

Comment: This simply loops through the checkboxes and un-checks them. For the correct answer, in VanillaJS, please see the answer of zahid ullah below.

Comment: How does this answer the question? This does something completely unrelated to what is asked. Why are there so many upvotes? Am I missing something, or was the question edited after people upvoted it?

Answer (score 46):

I didnt test it but it should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selected = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
       selected.push($(this).val());
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: push to add value in array but what to remove on uncheck?

Answer (score 41):

Pure JavaScript with no need for temporary variables:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name=type]:checked"), e => e.value);
```

Comment: it should be `...map((i,e) => e.value))` actually...

Comment: @spetsnaz index is the SECOND element, so if you need the index you need to do (e,i). Which of course is not necessary in this case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Nice one line solution. Can be easily reused in a method with input name as parameter and a return statement to get the array.

Comment: very nice, I think you should add `const checked =`

Answer (score 32):

**ES6 version:**

```
const values = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'))
  .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
  .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
```

```js
function getCheckedValues() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'))
  .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
  .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
}

const resultEl = document.getElementById('result');

document.getElementById('showResult').addEventListener('click', () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = getCheckedValues();
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />5

<br><br>
<button id="showResult">Show checked values</button>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 23):

This should do the trick:

```
$('input:checked');
```

I don't think you've got other elements that can be checked, but if you do, you'd have to make it more specific:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked');

$('input:checkbox').filter(':checked');
```

Comment: this does not answer the question on hoe to put the values into an array

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use a vanilla JS, you can do it similarly to a @zahid-ullah, but avoiding a loop:

```
  var values = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('fruits[]'), function(c) {
    return c.checked;
  }).map(function(c) {
    return c.value;
  });
```

The same code in ES6 looks a way better:

```
var values = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('fruits[]'), (c) => c.checked).map(c => c.value);
```

```js
window.serialize = function serialize() {
  var values = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('fruits[]'), function(c) {
    return c.checked;
  }).map(function(c) {
    return c.value;
  });
  document.getElementById('serialized').innerText = JSON.stringify(values);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="banana">Banana
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple">Apple
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="peach">Peach
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="orange">Orange
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="strawberry">Strawberry
</label>
<button onclick="serialize()">Serialize
</button>
<div id="serialized">
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

In MooTools 1.3 (latest at the time of writing):

```
var array = [];
$$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(i){
    array.push( i.value );
});
```

Comment: Didn't realise the age of the question or nature of solution was relevant.

Comment: Because I found this question when looking for the answer to the same problem using MooTools.

Comment: Note this answer relates to MooTools 1.3, not jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

In Javascript it would be like this [(Demo Link)](http://jsbin.com/nudoridavo/2/):

```
// get selected checkboxes
function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
  var selchbox = [];// array that will store the value of selected checkboxes
  // gets all the input tags in frm, and their number
  var inpfields = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;
  // traverse the inpfields elements, and adds the value of selected (checked) checkbox in selchbox
  for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
  }
  return selchbox;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox.vdrSelected:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this with vanilla JS in modern browsers (no IE support, and sadly no iOS Safari support at the time of writing) is with [FormData.getAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll):

```
var formdata   = new FormData(document.getElementById("myform"));
var allchecked = formdata.getAll("type"); // "type" is the input name in the question

// allchecked is ["1","3","4","5"]  -- if indeed all are checked
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var arr = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

On checking add the value for checkbox and on dechecking subtract the value

```js
$('#myDiv').change(function() {
  var values = 0.00;
  {
    $('#myDiv :checked').each(function() {
      //if(values.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1){
      values=values+parseFloat(($(this).val()));
      // }
    });
    console.log( parseFloat(values));
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4.00" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3.75" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1.25" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5.50" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation to your answer. Pure code answers aren't usually useful.

Answer (score 3):

Select Checkbox by input name

```
var category_id = [];

$.each($("input[name='yourClass[]']:checked"), function(){                    
    category_id.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.from($(".yourclassname:checked"), a => a.value);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

You only need to add class to every input, i have add class "source" you can change it of course

```
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" />
<input class="source" type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_value = []; // initialize empty array 
    $(".source:checked").each(function(){
        selected_value.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(selected_value); //Press F12 to see all selected values
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function selectedValues(ele){
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){
    if(ele[i].type == 'checkbox' && ele[i].checked){
      arr.push(ele[i].value);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! It would be nice if you would read this guide [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and adjust your answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = []
    $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function(){
        array.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

can use this function that I created

```
function getCheckBoxArrayValue(nameInput){
    let valores = [];
    let checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="'+nameInput+'"]:checked');
    checked.forEach(input => {
        let valor = input?.defaultValue || input?.value;
        valores.push(valor);
    });
    return(valores);
}
```

to use it just call it that way

```
getCheckBoxArrayValue("type");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get all checked values

```
        var yourArray=[];
        $("input[name='ordercheckbox']:checked").each(function(){
            yourArray.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var checked= $('input[name="nameOfCheckbox"]:checked').map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer a bit similar to @enguerranws 's one:

```
$('.your-check-box-class:checked').toArray().map(x =>x.value);
```

assuming all the checkbox of said group are using the `.your-check-box-class` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use commented if block to prevent add values which has already in array if you use button click or something to run the insertion

```js
$('#myDiv').change(function() {
  var values = [];
  {
    $('#myDiv :checked').each(function() {
      //if(values.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1){
      values.push($(this).val());
      // }
    });
    console.log(values);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="4" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="5" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
       var checkedValue = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
                return this.value;
            }).get();         
            alert(checkedValue);   //display selected checkbox value     
 })
```

Here

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() call when any checkbox checked or unchecked, after this
$('input:checkbox:checked').map(function()  looping on all checkbox,
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my code for the same problem someone can also try this.
**jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){`
$(".check11").change(function(){
var favorite1 = [];        
$.each($("input[name='check1']:checked"), function(){                    
favorite1.push($(this).val());
document.getElementById("countch1").innerHTML=favorite1;
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var idsComenzi = [];

    $('input:checked').each(function(){
        idsComenzi.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my two cents, in case it helps someone :

```
const data = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').toArray().map((item) => item.value);
```

I already had a jQuery object, so I wouldn't select all my checkbox another time, that's why I used jQuery's filter method. Then I convert it to a JS array, and I map the array to return items'value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var arr =[];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
     //arr.push($(this).parent('p').text()+'\n');
     arr.push($(this).val()+'\n');
    });
    var array = arr.toString().split(',')
    $("#text").val(array.join(""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Append value when checkbox is checked</p>
<textarea rows="4" id="text" style="width: 100%">
</textarea>


<div id="checkboxes">
  <p><input type="checkbox" value="Item 1"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 1</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" value="Item 2"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 2</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" value="Item 3"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 3</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" value="Item 4"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 4</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" value="Item 5"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 5</span></p>
</div>
```