# jquery multiple checkboxes array

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5" />
```

How I can make an array with values of checkboxes that are checked?

NOTE: (IMPORTANT) I need an array like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and not like ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] .

NOTE: There are around 50 checkboxes.

Can someone help me? Please!

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all selected checkboxes in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590018/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
var checked = []
$("input[name='options[]']:checked").each(function ()
{
    checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

Answer (score 58):

You can use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) (or even the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function that operates on a jQuery object) to get an array of checked values. The unary (+) operator will cast the string to a number

```
var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e,i) {
    return +e.value;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Here's [**an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/NxATD/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Do you know how to add the checked values to an input not span? I tried `$('#test').val(arr.join(','));`

Comment: You can shorten it even more e.g. `var arr 
 = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), (e) => +e.value);`

Answer (score 3):

```
var checkedString = $('input:checkbox:checked.name').map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join();
```

Answer (score 3):

This way will let you add or remove values when you check or uncheck any checkbox named as `options[]`:

```
var checkedValues = [];
$("input[name='options[]']").change(function() {
    const intValue = parseInt($(this).val());
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkedValues.push(value);
    } else {
        const index = checkedValues.indexOf(value);
        if (index > -1) {
           checkedValues.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class for each of your input box, then you can do it as

```
        var checked = []
        $('input.Booking').each(function ()
        {
            checked.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

A global function that can be reused:

```
function getCheckedGroupBoxes(groupName) {

    var checkedAry= [];
    $.each($("input[name='" + groupName + "']:checked"), function () {
        checkedAry.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });

     return checkedAry;

}
```

where the groupName is the name of the group of the checkboxes, in you example :'options[]'

Answer (score 0):

**Pure javascript answer**

```
const checked = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=myCheckboxGroup]:checked`)).map(node=>node.value);
```