# Getting array of selected checkbox attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, checkbox

In the web application I'm currently working on there are a lot of places where I have many HTML checkboxes that I need to turn into a JS array of selected items. For example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="7">
<input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="11">
```

Then I have a lot of logic like this to pack the selected values into an array:

```js
var items = [];
$('.example[data-item]:checked').each(function (_, e) {
    items.push(Number($(e).data('item')));
});
```

My question is just this: Is there some nice way to do this in a one-liner (jQuery is allowed if needed), e.g.:

```
var items = /* magic */;
```

I realize I could write a function for this, and I will if there is no way to do it clearly otherwise, but I'm looking for some built-in JS magic that can do it all at once.

---

For completeness here's a snippet:

```js
$('#button').click(function () {
  var items = [];
  $('.example[data-item]:checked').each(function (_, e) {
    items.push(Number($(e).data('item')));
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(items));
});
```

```css
label { display: flex; align-items: center; }
div { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; }
button { margin: 1ex; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="3"> Item 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="5"> Item 5</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="7"> Item 7</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="11"> Item 11</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="13"> Item 13</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="17"> Item 17</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="19"> Item 19</label>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/  `var items = $('.example[data-item]:checked').map(function() {
    return Number($(this).data('item'));
  }).get();`

Comment: @Jason ... Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/NxATD/ .. Source is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166763/jquery-multiple-checkboxes-array

Comment: @Shiladitya Oh awesome, so easy. Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/jmc2wzt8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code but another way could be to use `map()` and return what you need:

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  var items = $(".example[data-item]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).data('item');
  }).get();
  console.log(items);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  margin: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="3"> Item 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="5"> Item 5</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="7"> Item 7</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="11"> Item 11</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="13"> Item 13</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="17"> Item 17</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="example" data-item="19"> Item 19</label>
  <button id="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, and I made it even shorter with `var items = $.map($('.example[data-item]:checked'), (e) => +e.dataset.item);` (Just discovered the `+` trick from [jquery multiple checkboxes array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166791/616460)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use map function:

```
var tempValue=$('input:checkbox').map(function(n){
          if(this.checked){
                return  this.value;
              };
       }).get().join(',');
   console.log(tempValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const checkedItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[checked]')).reduce((items, el) => {
   // save whatever you want from the elmenent here
   items = items.concat(el)
   return items;
}, [])
```