# find selected checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this structure:

```html
<div id="fields" class="grid">
    <div>...<div>
    <div id="some_id_1" class="itemSortable">
        <input ...>
        <input ...>
        <div>
            <input id="selected" name="selected" type="checkbox" value="true">
            <input name="selected" type="hidden" value="false">
            ...
        </div>
    <div id="some_id_2" class="itemSortable">
        <input ...>
        <input ...>
        <div>
            <input id="selected" name="selected" type="checkbox" value="true">
            <input name="selected" type="hidden" value="false">
            ...
        </div>
     ...
    <div id="some_id_n" class="itemSortable">
        <input ...>
        <input ...>
        <div>
            <input id="selected" name="selected" type="checkbox" value="true">
            <input name="selected" type="hidden" value="false">
            ...
        </div>
</div>
```

I have no experience with jQuery so I am stuck. Can somebody help with jQuery script to get an array of all ids (Eg. `some_id_x`) for selected checkboxes?

Comment: `$(".grid .input[type='checkbox']:checked")` will return all of the selected checkbox elements.

Comment: I think this should answer your question!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590018/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array

Comment: None of the checkboxes in your code are in fact checked / selected, so the answer is always `[]` :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Sorry I cannot vote up for all useful answers here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you get the checkboxes themselves:

```
$(':input:checked');
```

Then you find their respective parents:

```
$(':input:checked').parents('.itemSortable');
```

To get each id, use `.each()` to iterate over the resulting list:

```
var ids = [];
$(':input:checked').parents('.itemSortable').each(function() {
    ids.push(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To get an array of the `id`s of the closest parent `.itemSortable` of the selected checkboxes, try this:

```
var idArray = $('#fields').find(':checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.itemSortable').prop('id');
}).get();
```

You seem to have a lot of duplicate `id` attributes though which means your HTML is invalid and will lead to problems in your code.

Comment: I think he wants to know the parent element's ID, so return `$(this).parents("div.itemSortable").attr("id");` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

css id's are meant to only be on 1 element on a page, use classes.

`$('.someClass:checked').serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

use **:checked Selector**

Details on http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Example:

```
$(function()
{
    var idArray = new Array(); $('#fields').find(':checked').each(function() 
   {
       idArray.push(this.id);
   });

   console.log(idArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to retrieve the checked inputs of type check (check-boxes), use the `":checked"` selector.
this example can explain my point:

Html:

```
<div id="fields" class="grid">
        <div id="some_id_1" class="itemSortable">
            <div>
                <input id="selected" name="selected" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="some_id_2" class="itemSortable">
            <div>
                <input id="selected" name="selected" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div id="some_id_n" class="itemSortable">
            <div>
                <input id="selected" name="selected" type="checkbox" value="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            alert($("#fields :checked").length);
        });
```

this example will alert number two; the count of checked check-boxes in element with id `"fields"` .

PS:

- I hope this is what you have requested.
- to make input of type checkbox is checked use the attribute `checked="checked"`