# How to check checkbox array along with text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML page with javascript. In this, I have form which contains text for name and checkboxes. Below is the HTML form:

```
<form name="drugForm" action="form1.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"     method="post">
     First name: <input type="text" name="dname">
     <pre>      
      <input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="id1">ID1        <input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="id2">ID2</br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="id3">ID3        <input type="checkbox" name="drug" value="id4">ID4</br>
     </pre>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Below is the javascript for same:

```
<script>
    function validateForm(){
        var x=document.forms["drugForm"]["dname"].value;
        //var y=document.drugForm.drug[0].value;
        var y = new Array();

        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("First name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
        else if (Boolean(x))
        {
            alert("click any checkbox "+ y);
            //alert("Working with boolean " + y);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here, I want to check whether any checkbox is checked also along with name entry. But whenever I am trying to put for loop with y (array) in else if condition or anywhere in function, the code is not working and instead giving action directly.

My question, specifically, is how to check checkboxes, like did in if condition, is checked and how to get those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below validate when there's at least one checked box:

```
function validateForm(){
    var x=document.forms["drugForm"]["dname"].value;
    var y=document.drugForm.drug;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    } else if (Boolean(x)) {
        for (k=0;k<y.length;k++) {
            if(y[k].checked) {
            return true;
            }
        }
        alert("Check one option at least");
        return false;
    }
}
```

There's another goog option in jquery as shown in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590018/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function validateForm(){
     var x=document.forms["drugForm"]["dname"].value;
     if (x==null || x=="")
     {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
     }
     else if (x)
     {
         if(!$('input:checkbox:checked').length)//check length of checked checkboxes
         {
             alert("click any checkbox ");
             return false;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: if(!$('input:checkbox:checked').length)//check length of checked checkboxes
         {
             alert("click any checkbox ");  With above piece of code also it is directing me to action page.
             return false;
         }