# trying to get all checkboxes from full page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all checked chckboxes value of a full page.

the full has all sort of html tags defined.

There is another piece to it which is div which has a parent class of `"syllabus"`. except that class div and any checkboxes inside it will be ignored when the other checkboxes of complete page is checked

I am trying some like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
});
```

Comment: That looks good, apart from the fact that you are overwriting `sThisVal` each time you loop over your checkboxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590018/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var sThisVal = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
  sThisVal.push((this.checked ? $(this).val() : ""));
});

console.log(sThisVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked value="1">Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2">Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" checked value="3">Checkbox 3
<input type="checkbox"value="4">Checkbox 4
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
var checkedValues = [];

$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    checkedValues.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(checkedValues);
```

Or (using `.map()` and `.get()`)

```
var checkedValues = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(checkedValues);
```

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/map/)