# Is there a way to get checkbox's checked value in array? [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

[image: Checkbox generated based on data]

> 

This checkbox [ looks like toggle button] generated based on data.
I want to get checked values in an array.

**Code**

```
{this.state.customersmsselect.map((e, key) => {
  
  if(e.isactive == "ON"){
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <div className="form-group col-md-8">
        <label className="col-md-4 control-label">{e.notificationtype}</label>
        <div className="col-md-4 smart-form">
          <label className="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id={"smscheckbox" + key} value={e.isactive + "," + e.smstemplateid} name={"checkbox-toggle"+e.smstemplateid} onChange={this.onChangeFavorite} defaultChecked />
            <i data-swchoff-text='OFF' data-swchon-text='ON' ></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style={{ margin: 10 }}>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  );
```

**My onChange method**

If click on that button then I will get, that button's name.

```
   onChangeFavorite(event) {
     if(!event.target.checked){
        console.log(event.target.name);
     }
   };
```

**My customersmsselect array looks like**

```
0: {smstemplateid: "1", notificationtype: "Invoice Details", isactive: "ON"}
1: {smstemplateid: "2", notificationtype: "Payment Thank-You", isactive: "ON"}
2: {smstemplateid: "3", notificationtype: "Daily Closing Balance", isactive: "OFF"}
3: {smstemplateid: "4", notificationtype: "Monthly Closing Balance", isactive: "ON"}
```

**Problem**

I want to get all the checked values in an array when I click on the button.

Comment: looks like duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590018/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array

Comment: I want a solution to react, I do not want to use Jquery to manipulate DOM

Comment: You have to capture the CheckBox state in the OnChange event and store it in a state object. Then get the values from State whenever required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can instead use controlled inputs. Then we need to bind the checked attribute and set the state in onChange handler. `checked={e.isactive === "ON"}` checks the checkbox depending on the value. `onChange={()=>this.onChangeFavorite(e)}` will attach the event handler along with the customersmsselect item which is being mapped.

```
x.isactive = x.isactive === "OFF" ? "ON" : "OFF";
        this.setState({
          customersmsselect: this.state.customersmsselect
});
```

Does the required checking of the input.

```
{this.state.customersmsselect.map((e, key) => {
  $('#s').val(key);
  if(e.isactive == "ON"){
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <div className="form-group col-md-8">
        <label className="col-md-4 control-label">{e.notificationtype}</label>
        <div className="col-md-4 smart-form">
          <label className="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id={"smscheckbox" + key} value={e.isactive + "," + e.smstemplateid} name={"checkbox-toggle"+e.smstemplateid} onChange={()=>this.onChangeFavorite(e)} checked={e.isactive === "ON"} />
            <i data-swchoff-text='OFF' data-swchon-text='ON' ></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style={{ margin: 10 }}>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Then

```
onChangeFavorite(x) {
     //Here now we are directly changing the array element value. 
     //Since its in the state when we change and assign it will automatically
     //update the controlled components.


    x.isactive = x.isactive === "OFF" ? "ON" : "OFF";
    this.setState({
      customersmsselect: this.state.customersmsselect
    });
};
```

Comment: If you have doubts on this solution feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

you can try use ref like this:

```
{this.state.customersmsselect.map((e, key) => {
  $('#s').val(key);
  if(e.isactive == "ON"){
  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <div className="form-group col-md-8">
        <label className="col-md-4 control-label">{e.notificationtype}</label>
        <div className="col-md-4 smart-form">
          <label className="toggle">
            <input type="checkbox" id={"smscheckbox" + key} value={e.isactive + "," + e.smstemplateid} name={"checkbox-toggle"+e.smstemplateid} onChange={this.onChangeFavorite} defaultChecked ref={node => { this.checkBoxes[key] = node; }} />
            <i data-swchoff-text='OFF' data-swchon-text='ON' ></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style={{ margin: 10 }}>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  );
```

then you can refer to this.checkBoxes as a regular array

Comment: I think ref is not required here. We can achieve this without ref.

Comment: agree for the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your input field:

```
<input type="checkbox" id={"smscheckbox" + key} value={e.isactive} name={"checkbox-toggle"+e.smstemplateid} onChange={(event) => this.onChangeFavorite(event, key)} checked={e.isactive === "ON"} />
```

Your onChange event:

```
onChangeFavorite(event, index) {
  const shouldBeOnOrOff =
    this.state.customersmsselect[index].isactive === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
  this.setState({
    customersmsselect: this.state.customersmsselect.map((item, i) =>
      index === i ? { ...item, isactive: shouldBeOnOrOff } : item
    )
  });
}
```

This will give you an array of objects that are currently ON:

```
this.state.customersmsselect.filter((item) => item.isactive === "ON");
```

This will give you an array of IDs that are currently ON, which I assume is the value you want?

```
this.state.customersmsselect.filter((item) => item.isactive === "ON").map((item) => item.smstemplateid);
```

---

**DEMO:** https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-morning-j6dbx?fontsize=14