# Event to handle selected checkboxes inside table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox, office-addins

I am using Office JS API to create an Office add-in, and wanted to capture checkbox events when selecting values. I call an API that returns a JSON object, with a key-value pair, where the value is an array of strings. I then display the object as a table.

I have a table tag:

```
<table id="out-table"></table>
```

..and a button:

```
<button class="ms-Button ms-Button--hero" id="sim">Process</button>
```

..which is triggered by:

```
document.getElementById("sim").onclick = process;
```

..and in my JS code (inside the `process` function), I create the table rows and data values:

```
const table = document.getElementById("out-table");

proposals.forEach((pr, idx) => {
    const sm = summaries[idx];

    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    const prElement = document.createElement("td");
    const smElement = document.createElement("td");

    prElement.style.fontSize = "9px";
    prElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    smElement.style.fontSize = "9px";

    const prContent = document.createTextNode(pr);
    const smContent = document.createTextNode(truncate(sm, 150));

    const prSelect = document.createElement("input");
    prSelect.type = "checkbox";
    prSelect.id = "ss"; // does this make sense to have it the same ID?
    prSelect.value = pr;

    const label = document.createElement("label");
    label.htmlFor = pr;

    prElement.appendChild(prSelect);
    prElement.appendChild(label);
    prElement.appendChild(prContent);
    smElement.appendChild(smContent);

    row.appendChild(prElement);
    row.appendChild(smElement);

    table.appendChild(row);
  });
```

..where proposals and summaries are arrays of strings. The input element created just adds a checkbox before the prContent with its label so it something like this:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| [x] V1 | row |
| [ ] V2 | row |

When the table is populated, I want to multi-select the checkboxes then press a button that captures the values (V1, V2), and use them - log them for example. How would I do this? I want to be able to dynamically select and deselect and press a button that outputs only the selected values.

Comment: can you create a code pen or a stackblitz or jsfiddle to demo your full code

Comment: I'll try but unfortunately running everything on a custom Office NodeJS project (yeoman generator for office), and I would have to include everything. It's a PowerPoint add-in project.

Comment: this isn't relevant to the table at all, isn't it? here's how you can collect values from an array of checkboxes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015793/3807365