# laravel cannot store multiple values from checkbox

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I am trying to do some small laravel exercise. I wanna store multiple values from the checkbox. I have 2 checkboxes, the value for 2 checkbox is 2 and 3, if I clicked 2 checkbox, I wanna return '2,3', if i just clicked one checkbox, the corresponding value is returned.
here is my mark up:

```
<input type="hidden" name="approved" value="1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" value="2" {{ old('approved', 1) == 2 ? 'checked' : '' }}></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" value="3" {{ old('approved', 1) == 3 ? 'checked' : '' }}></input>
```

here is my script to pass the checkbox value to the controller:

```
approved:$('input[name="approved[]"]:checked').val(),
```

here is my controller:

```
$approved = $request->input('approved',1);
$approved = implode(",", $approved);
```

the result is: only "2" is returned if I clicked 2 checkbox together, and the right corresponding value could be returned if I just clicked single checkbox. Can you please help me to figure it out? MANY THANKS!

here is my edition:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" value="2" {{ in_array('2', old('approved', [])) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
<input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" value="3" {{ in_array('3', old('approved', [])) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

I have a submit button to connect with the controller, here is my JS part:

```
 $('#submit-btn').on('click',function(event){
         $('input[name="approved[]"]').on('change', function() {
         var checkedValues = $('input[name="approved[]"]:checked').map(function() {
           return this.value;
       }).get();
         var ans = $('#approved').val(checkedValues.join(','));
    });
       
         event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'XXXXXX',
                method: 'post',
                data:{
                      approved: ans,
                },})
```

here is the controller:

```
$approved = $request->input('approved', []);
```

now the result returned is null

Comment: Hope this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590018/getting-all-selected-checkboxes-in-an-array

Comment: @VinodPatidar I think the questions are same, and I tried the first answer but null is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Form**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" value="2" {{ in_array('2', old('approved', [])) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
<input type="checkbox" name="approved[]" value="3" {{ in_array('3', old('approved', [])) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

**Javascript**

```
var approvedValues = $('input[name="approved[]"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

**Controller**

```
$approved = $request->input('approved', []);
$approvedString = implode(",", $approved);
```

Comment: can I ask if it would be better that I don't use the hidden value, cuz all I need is just store 2 values that I checked in the checkbox

Comment: @RA.IBOY I added to my answer

Comment: hi, @KarlHill I updated the markup and controller according to your second method and the JS in your first method. But null is returned this time. I just updated my code and provided more information, can you please have a look on my question part? THANKS!

Comment: hi @KarlHill, Really THANKS! It worked now, and would you like to update your answer a little bit? I think there is no need to convert variable to $approved to string in the controller, cuz the variable approvedValues passed from JS is already string.